Askinu seudasa on Yom Tov
The Chabad nusach has a form of אתקינו סעודתא in kiddush (both day and night) for the shalosh regalim. However, it is not found in the machzor for Rosh Hashanah. I'm trying to find out if there are other customs, or if anyone discusses the reason for the difference in practice between R"H and the regalim.

Shaar HaKollel says to say אלה מועדי before R"H kiddush as well, presumably preceded by אתקינו. But I don't think that's the custom today.

Nice! Yeah, in current editions of the machzor, kiddusha rabba for weekday R"H starts with ת​ק​ע​ו ב​ח​ד​ש ש​ו​פ​ר.
